# Google map drags while scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I used a Google map in my site, and the container div which contains the map is draggable. Now my problem is that when I scroll the map, it also drags. I want to stop dragging when of map scrolling. How can I do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you provide more detail? If the google map fully fills your div, how do you plan to drag the div? If it does not fully fill the div (say there is a border around the map), then in the mouseDown you can check the sender is the div and not the map. Then you can move the map by dragging the map, or the div and map by dragging the border.

Comment: Seems a bit harsh to get an anonymous -1 given the question is vague and I gave a reasonable answer and the OP accepted. Someone was hoping for more?